# how can solve : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to android.net.Uri

Tags: android, bitmap, intentservice

when time to i share image on whats app facebook ect. its failed to file read and throw exeption Caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to android.net.Uri
11-23 12:32:02.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11662):         at com.whatsapp.ContactPicker.d(ContactPicker.java:531)
11-23 12:32:02.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11662):         at com.whatsapp.ContactPicker.onCreate(ContactPicker.java:306)
11-23 12:32:02.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11662):         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
11-23 12:32:02.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11662):         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
11-23 12:32:02.835: E/AndroidRuntime(11662):         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
```

My activity:

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;
    Button buttonsetwallpaper, share;
    String sp_items[] = new String[] { "Setwallpaper", "Share", "Exit" };
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
        buttonsetwallpaper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wallpaper);
        buttonsetwallpaper.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00,
                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();
        final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        final ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

        share.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Bitmap o = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/." + img_name);
                // Bitmap o =
                // BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/wallpaperapp/");
                Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
                // Bitmap mBitmap =
                // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),(int)i.getItemId(position));
                try {

                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("image/png");
                    System.out.println("*********************" + mBitmap);
                    share.putExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            scaleDownBitmap(mBitmap, 90, FullImageActivity.this));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this,
                    // "Error setting wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        buttonsetwallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Bitmap o = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/." + img_name);
                // Bitmap o =
                // BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/wallpaperapp/");
                Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
                // Bitmap mBitmap =
                // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),(int)i.getItemId(position));

                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                        .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(mBitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, "Wallpaper set",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this,
                            "Error setting wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight, Context context) {

        final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().density;

        int h = (int) (newHeight * densityMultiplier);
        int w = (int) (h * photo.getWidth() / ((double) photo.getHeight()));

        photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

        return photo;
    }
```

---

my image in layout folder with save into sdcard i want to share here i give my code plz help me.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
ImageView imageView;
// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.a3,
        R.drawable.a10, R.drawable.a11, R.drawable.a12, R.drawable.a13,
        R.drawable.a14, R.drawable.a15, R.drawable.a16, R.drawable.a17,
        R.drawable.a18, R.drawable.a19, R.drawable.a20, R.drawable.a21,

        R.drawable.a22, R.drawable.a23, R.drawable.a24, R.drawable.a25,
        R.drawable.a26, R.drawable.a27, R.drawable.a28, R.drawable.a30,
        R.drawable.a31, R.drawable.a32, R.drawable.a33, R.drawable.a34,
        R.drawable.a35, R.drawable.a36, R.drawable.a37,

        R.drawable.a38, R.drawable.a39, R.drawable.a4, R.drawable.a40,
        R.drawable.a41, R.drawable.a42, R.drawable.a43, R.drawable.a5,
        R.drawable.a6, R.drawable.a7, R.drawable.a8, R.drawable.a9,
        R.drawable.aa9

};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 300));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return imageView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In this line you have to pass the saved image uri instead of `Bitamp`

```
 share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    scaleDownBitmap(mBitmap, 90, FullImageActivity.this));
```

change like this..

```
Bitmap icon=scaleDownBitmap(mBitmap, 90, FullImageActivity.this);
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg")
```

screenshotUri is the Uri path of your image.

another way is..

```
Bitmap icon=scaleDownBitmap(mBitmap, 90, FullImageActivity.this);
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bytes.toByteArray());
```

Comment: but i get image via its position so how can set Uri and i click on grid view in any image its open in new activity i want to share this image but i dont know what write in Uri

Comment: For this you have to save the image somewher and get the path and and then you have get the uri..

Comment: Add permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: i am again update my qustion my image is present in drawable folder how to get path in this code

Comment: you can get path like this..Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/image_name");

Answer (score 0):

in your `share` on click listener, where you have written this line below, this line is the error :-

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,scaleDownBitmap(mBitmap, 90, FullImageActivity.this));
```

in this you are calling the `scaleDownBtmap` function which returns a BITMAP. Now inten.putExtra method does not take a Bitmap Argument, that is why you are getting that class cast exception. You need to convert your bitmap in bytestream and then pass it in the put extra method.
    Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight, Context context) {

```
final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources()
        .getDisplayMetrics().density;

int h = (int) (newHeight * densityMultiplier);
int w = (int) (h * photo.getWidth() / ((double) photo.getHeight()));

photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

return photo;
```

}

putExtra method does not take a Bitmap argument.
**Do this :-**

```
Bitmap b = scaleDownBitmap(mBitmap, 90, FullImageActivity.this); // your bitmap // use your scaleDownBitmap ere
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
share.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
```

then in the receiving activity, you convert this bytestream into a bitmap :-

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
    getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
```